# Overflow issue in IE 7

Tags: css, overflow

I need some help with CSS overflow in IE, namely IE 7.  I want the nested div content to be hidden.

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden; border:1px dashed red;">
    <div style="width:60px; left:80px; position:relative;">hidden stuff goes here</div>
</div>
```

It works fine in FF but in IE 7, the overflow content is not hidden.

Comment: At what point should the content get hidden though? Your inner box isn't as wide as the box with overflow: hidden, so you will see the overflow until 100px in IE. Move the overflow: hidden to the inner box if that's where you want it to apply.

Comment: If you want to hide the div, you could use a display:none in the style of the second div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add display:none to the inner div and it will be hidden. I think you are mis-understanding the use of overflow:hidden though...

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden; border:1px dashed red;">
        <div style="width:60px; left:80px; position:relative; display:none;">hidden stuff goes here</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's quite possible that you're right about me misunderstanding the use of overflow:hidden as I'm still new at all of this.  This was part of a scrollable jquery widget and the CSS for IE was baffling me.  However, I removed position:relative and used margin-left instead of left and I got the results that I needed.  Thanks for helping out though!